# find max of a function that depends on unknown lagrange multipliers

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

i want to find the max of a function f, I take that first derivative and solve the equation equals to zero, so the solution is x=$sqrt((l1+l2)/(l1))$, where l1,l2 are lagrange multipliers (previous work). I have to find the max, so if I take l1<0 and l1+l2 <0 that means that this x is the optimal solution (second derivative depend on l1, so it is negative). Is this thought correct?
f:=$-l1*x+l1*z*x.^3-l2*x$

max (f)

where l1,l2 lagrange and z a constant positive value

Comment: You should include all relevant information, including the statement of the initial problem, as well as your steps up to now, so that we can help you. Also, please try to use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to typeset your equations.

Comment: i think is better